# ComboBox not recognizing first character

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a really weird issue that affects only a few users...

I have an ASP.NET site with an AJAX Control Toolkit combobox. When these users try typing in the combobox, the first character they type is often not recognized. They often need to hit the key twice to get it to register.

At first I thought this was an issue with their keyboards, so I had one of the users try on my keyboard. She was able to duplicate the behavior. However, when I try, it's usually fine. (I've only been able to successfully duplicate this once)

Is this a keyboard issue, or is there something else I can look at? The standard browser here is IE9.

**EDIT**

I've been able to reliably duplicate the "problem"...

When a user engages the dropdownlist and then starts typing, *the first keystroke sets focus back in the textbox.* This creates the illusion that the first keystroke didn't register. I hate to say it, but this appears to be by design. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could it be possible that you have more than one event capturing key presses?

Comment: Are you using the Ajax Control Toolkit Script Manager and not the generic Script Manager on your page with the combobox? I know that using the generic one with the ajax controls can cause some weird behavior.